# AES do I need to split my decoded message to chunks

Tags: c#, aes

I have a picture and I want to encrypt it using AES, do I need to split it to chunks? (because if I get a key with the size of 256 bits and my message is bigger, if I xor them, most of the message will remain the decoded message, so how will that help?)

if yes, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES is not XOR encrpytion and you do not need to block

```
            // this could also just be a byte array
            string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";

            using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
            {

                // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, 
                                   myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
                string roundtrip = 
                         DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, 
                              myAes.Key, myAes.IV);


            }
```